# CSS селектор, который изменяет стили в зависимости от наличия блока

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Нужно написать такой селектор, который будет изменять стили input в зависимости от наличия блока с классом icon

Пример кода:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        Текст
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <input type="" name=""> <!-- Инпут с отступом 20px слева-->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="foo">
        Текст
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <input type="" name=""> <!-- Инпут без отступа-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужно-то нужно, но таких селекторов не существует. при формировании верстки к блоку `block` добавляейте какой-нить `no-icon` класс, если внутри нет `.icon`. Пишите стили для `.block input` и перекрывайте их в `.block.no-icon input`. либо наоборот с `.has-icon`

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, на сегодняшний момент (сентябрь 2020), реализовать задумку в полной мере только средствами CSS невозможно.

Всё было бы намного проще, если бы утвердили селектор [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:has):

```css
.foo:has(.icon) ~ .bar input {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Но, не смотря на то, что обсуждается он давно (и даже имеет поддержку в JS) - "[воз и ныне там](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational)"...

---

Возможен вариант с использованием селектора `:empty`, но это не то, что Вам нужно, так как блок `.foo` должен быть полностью пустым (от пробельных символов включительно):

```css
.foo:empty ~ .bar input {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    Текст
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <input value="icon"><!-- Инпут с отступом 20px слева-->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="bar">
    <input value="no icon"><!-- Инпут с отступом 20px слева-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Тем не менее, если текст в `.foo` является всего лишь меткой, не содержит много символов и не изменяется, то предыдущий вариант возможен, с переносом текста в псевдоэлемент:

```css
.foo {
  position: relative;
}

.foo::before {
  content: "Текст";
  position: relative;
}

.foo:empty~.bar input {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <input value="icon"><!-- Инпут с отступом 20px слева-->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="bar">
    <input value="no icon"><!-- Инпут без отступа-->
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Лучшим выходом будет - добавление классов при формировании разметки или манипуляции через скрипты после добавления.*